# Mikro-Orm: EntityManager Type Error (this.config.getComparator is not a function)

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, mikro-orm

I'm currently working through the Ben Awad Fullstack tutorial but I keep running into an error I can't resolve or find any mention of on StackOverflow, I might be missing something simple.

Here's the error:

```
[nodemon] starting `node dist/index.js`
breakpoint 1
[discovery] ORM entity discovery started, using ReflectMetadataProvider
[discovery] - processing entity Post
[discovery] - entity discovery finished, found 1 entities, took 15 ms
TypeError: this.config.getComparator is not a function
```

The location of the error resolves back to EntityManager.js in Mikro-ORM core. I've tried comparing files to the tutorial Github and reviewing my own files in detail, I also tried searching on here for a similar error but could not find anything.

Here is what my code and config files look like:

index.ts:

```
import {MikroORM} from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post"
import microConfig from "./mikro-orm.config";

const main =  async() => {
    console.log("breakpoint 1");
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
    await orm.getMigrator().up();
    console.log("breakpoint 2");
    const post = orm.em.create(Post, {title: "my first post"});    
    await orm.em.persistAndFlush(post);
};

main().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The first console.log does run, but it errors out on the next line (const orm =...).

The Post.ts file:

```
import { Entity, PrimaryKey, Property } from "@mikro-orm/core";

@Entity()
export class Post {

  @PrimaryKey()
  id!: number;

  @Property({type: "date"})
  createdAt = new Date();
  
  @Property( {type:"date",onUpdate: () => new Date() })
  updatedAt = new Date();

  @Property({type: "text"})
  title!: string;
}
```

Mikro-orm.config.ts:

```
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import path from "path";
//import { User } from "./entities/User";

export default {
  migrations: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./migrations"),
    pattern: /^[\w-]+\d+\.[tj]s$/,
  },
  entities: [Post],//, User],
  dbName: "lireddit",
  user: 'postgres',
  password: 'postgres',
  type: "postgresql",
  debug: !__prod__
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

I'm using the following versions/packages: node 17.0.10, mikro-orm 4.5.1 (core,cli,migrations,postgresql), typescript 4.5.5, ts-node: 10.4.0

I think this might be my first post here, so please let me know if there's any thing I should include or omit in future, thanks!

Comment: Hard to be sure without full reproduction, but you probably have version mismatch in the ORM packages. My guess is your migrations package is on different (incompatible) version than the core package. Try upgrading all packages to latest, wipe your lock file and node_modules (and dist) and install again.

Comment: Note that there are some antipatterns in that tutorial, like the way you type it is both wrong (won't catch keys that are not valid) and unnecessary complex (just use `Options` exported from core package). See for example [this config](https://github.com/mikro-orm/nestjs-realworld-example-app/blob/master/src/mikro-orm.config.ts.example).

Comment: Thank you  Martin Adámek, it was some form of version mismatch. Wiping the files and reinstalling the most recent version of packages resolved the error. Now onto the next error. Appreciate your insight with regards to the antipattern as well, I'll take a look!